# How to delete point from spline

Tags: python, scripting

for my script I need an empty spline (with no points), but when I create a new spline, blender creates a new point within the spline.
How can I remove this point, so I am left with an empty spline?
points.remove() or points.pop() don't work, or I do something worng.

```
curve = bpy.data.curves.new(name='curve_data',type='CURVE')
curve.dimensions = '3D' 
curveObj = theObj = bpy.data.objects.new("curve_obj", curve)
bpy.context.collection.objects.link(curveObj)
polyline = curve.splines.new('POLY')
polyline.points.pop(0)
```

Answer (score 4):

#### Delete bezier curve vertice

```
import bpy

bpy.ops.curve.primitive_bezier_curve_add(radius=1, enter_editmode=False, align='WORLD', location=(0, 0, 0), scale=(1, 1, 1))
obj = bpy.context.object

splines     = obj.data.splines
bpy.ops.object.mode_set(mode = 'EDIT')
bpy.ops.curve.select_all(action='DESELECT')
bpy.ops.object.mode_set(mode = 'OBJECT')

line0   = splines[0]
pt      = line0.bezier_points[0]
pt.select_control_point = True

bpy.ops.object.mode_set(mode = 'EDIT')
bpy.ops.curve.delete(type='VERT')
bpy.ops.object.mode_set(mode = 'OBJECT')
```

#### Delete non-bezier curve vertice

```
import bpy

bpy.ops.curve.primitive_nurbs_path_add(radius=1, enter_editmode=False, align='WORLD', location=(0, 0, 0), scale=(1, 1, 1))
obj = bpy.context.object

splines     = obj.data.splines
bpy.ops.object.mode_set(mode = 'EDIT')
bpy.ops.curve.select_all(action='DESELECT')
bpy.ops.object.mode_set(mode = 'OBJECT')

line0       = splines[0]
pt          = line0.points[0]
pt.select   = True

bpy.ops.object.mode_set(mode = 'EDIT')
bpy.ops.curve.delete(type='VERT')
bpy.ops.object.mode_set(mode = 'OBJECT')
```

Answer (score 2):

Replace your last line with

```py
point = polyline.points[0]
point.select = True

bpy.context.view_layer.objects.active = curveObj
bpy.ops.object.mode_set(mode = 'EDIT')
bpy.ops.curve.delete(type='VERT')
```

You need to delete the specific control point, which can only be done in edit mode, which can only be set for the active object.

This is a specialization of the general case of deleting vertices from a curve.  `bpy.ops.curve.delete` deletes all of the *selected* control points; so you can iterate through the control points of a curve and set `select` for all of the points you want to delete before you call `bpy.ops.curve.delete`.